# Formatters %r and %s - difference in theory but this script says otherwise

Tags: python, formatter

I'm working through a Python tutorial that has repeatedly stated that %r is for debugging and is the raw representation whereas %s is the output.

But, consider this script from the tutorial:

```
age = raw_input("How old are you? ")
height = raw_input("What's your height? ")
weight = raw_input("What's your weight? ")

print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy" % (age, height, weight)
```

And that function runs fine.

But when I changed each instance of %r to %s, there was no change in output? I'd like to state what I expected to see but I was not sure. I was expecting (hoping) to see something that illustrated the difference.

Can someone clarify?

Comment: Are you sure there is absolutely no difference? With `%r`, the values should appear inside quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check better, there's quite of a difference:

```
>>> print "So, you're %r old, %r tall and %r heavy" % (age, height, weight)
So, you're '123' old, '456' tall and '789' heavy
>>> print "So, you're %s old, %s tall and %s heavy" % (age, height, weight)
So, you're 123 old, 456 tall and 789 heavy
>>>
```

The single quotes are there in the first output since the "raw representation" of a string requires it (i.e., to put a string literal inside Python code you need to delimit it with single or double quotes), where in the second output they aren't printed, since you asked just to print the string as it is.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I never noticed the single quotes

Answer (score 4):

`%r` calls `repr` whereas `%s` calls `str` when formatting the string:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __str__(self):
...         return 'foo'
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'bar'
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> '%s' % f
'foo'
>>> '%r' % f
'bar'
```

For objects which define `__repr__` and not `__str__`, [the output will be the same](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), however, for strings, there is a difference (notably an extra quotation):

```
>>> print str('foo')
foo
>>> print repr('foo')
'foo'
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. My tutorial has not covered Classes yet (though am sure it will soon). I'm pretty novice but am sure that this answer will help those more knowledgeable.